# Are OpenAPI 3.0 YAML spec complex paths allowed?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is this a legal path in an OpenAPI 3.0 yaml spec?

```
paths:
  /config/copy:
    get:
    ...
```

I have seen that this is not permitted with 2.0, but have found no info on 3.0.

So far I have only seen this when including parameters:

```
 paths:
      /user/{id}/posts/{id}:
        get:
        ...
```

Comment: These paths are perfectly valid in both OAS 2 and 3. _"I have seen that this is not permitted with 2.0"_ - where did you see this?

Comment: Have edited the question slightly to make clear the question refers to paths without query params

Comment: @Helen Are you saying that the first example is legal? Thx

Comment: Yes. Multi-segment paths are common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. From the specification:

```yaml
paths:
  /ping:
    ...
  /users:
    ...
  /users/{id}:
```

another example

```yaml
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      parameters:
```

Reference:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/

Comment: The reference docs are great, and I did search them, but found no examples of /longer/paths/without/params

Comment: They're also allowed. There's nothing special about `/urls/with/multiple/segments`